# Global Search in Moodle 3.2

Tags: macos, search, solr, moodle, pecl

I am trying to setup global Solr search in moodle 3.2 on mac and using MAMP (locally). I have installed Solr 6.6.1, and can access its admin panel through http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/ . But I am unable to link it with moodle through PECL Solr, the reasion is that I am unable to install PECL, I don't know where to place them, and how to link with moodle.

I am getting

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps to get **Solr** working in **Moodle**.

Step:1 Delete core you have created in **Solr**.

Step:2 Create new core

Step:3 filled core name into **Index name** filed of **Moodle Solr** setting.

Step:4 `sudo bin/solr stop -force`

Step:5 `sudo bin/solr start -force`

If not working yet then need to reboot the system and restart **Solr** again.
Hope it is done!